# How objects and its references work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I'm new to JavaScript so have a question on objects and their reference.
Let's say we have empty objects

```
{}=={}
```

if you write this line in console, it returns `false`

```
{}==={}
```

it returns `false` on above line of code too.

but let say we have

```
a=2
b=a
b==a
b===a
```

it returns `true` in this case.

can anyone please explain what's happening on back side in both cases?

Comment: The details are in [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-equality-operators).

Comment: short reasoning: 1) an assignment *never* creates a new object (primitives are immutable and have special conversion rules in equality, so wether or not they are copied is irrelevant); 2) `{}` (as expression) always creates a new object. (And mixing in a primitive type/value (`2`) does not help the question at all when comparing the behavior of the equality between Object values.)